# Menu button won't appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, tkinter

I'm using Python 3 and when i run this simple code the file menu wont appear. I was also trying to produce a drop down menu but can't even get this simple code to work.

```
import tkinter as tk



class AnimalDataPlotApp():

    def __init__(self,root):
        self._root = root
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        menubar = tk.Menu(self._root)
        menubar.add_command(label="File")

        self._root.config(menu=menubar)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = AnimalDataPlotApp(root)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you have to use pack() or grid() when you initialize and on each widget.

Comment: @BlivetWidget Thanks but i'm not sure exactly where or what to pack. i'm very new to GUI's

Comment: They can be very... interesting.  Mostly because they don't follow the same conventions as the rest of the language.  I'll post an answer, as it's a bit more involved than I can show in a comment.

Comment: @dflyn What do you mean `File` menu wont come? I tried your exact code, it came for me. When clicking on it, no drop down would come though (and thats expected) , is the drop down not coming, your issue?

Comment: @BlivetWidget  A Menu instance attached to a top level as the 'menu' attribute is automatically placed just under the top bar.  See my answer.  dflyn: no wonder you did not know how to pack it.  you don't.

Comment: heh, indeed, certainly works without.  Well, shows what I knew about menus, which which was apparently nothing.  I guess the answer then is that something needs to be added to the menu.

Comment: What does 'not work' mean?  I ran your code and see exactly what I expect -- a menu bar with 'File' that does nothing.  BlivitWidget is correct above -- you need more to get action.  I will add more to my answer.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: As you say it should work and I see it does with you. There is physically no File button as one would expect. When running the example code in the answer, I do See the File with drop down save and open options. Is it also expected that I see the menus not in the widget/ tk() window but instead at the top next to my Python control bar?? thank you for the support everyone

Comment: @TerryJanReedy please read above

Comment: @dflyn Would you mind putting a screenshot of the output you are getting?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'Python control bar'.  Are you running on Mac? It does funny things with certain menu items.

Answer (score 0):

(EDITED)

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Hello", command=lambda:print('Hello World'))
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=lambda:print('Open File'))
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=lambda:print('Save File'))
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

displays a window with a menu with two entries.  One invokes a command, the other a submenu. The minimal style is not meant to discourage writing a class.